# Graphs with a unique $3$-path free acyclic orientation up to isomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Let $\Gamma$ be a simple, $3$-colorable graph such that, up to isomorphism, there exists exactly one acyclic orientation of $\Gamma$ that does not contain a directed 3-path.  (To be clear, when I say $3$-path, I mean three edges, four vertices.) I require that $\Gamma$ is $3$-colorable so that at least one such orientation exists (this is an if and only if).

The $5$-cycle is an example of a graph with this property.  Up to isomorphism, the only orientation that meets this requirement is the following:

[image: Example: <span class=]$\overset{\rightharpoonup}{C_5}$." />

I have a few questions about these:

> I. Can graphs like this be characterized in some other way?  What is it that makes these guys only have one orientation?

There may be something to the *twisted orbital chromatic polynomial*, described briefly at the end of [document](https://webspace.maths.qmul.ac.uk/p.j.cameron/csgnotes/countcols.pdf).  Perhaps this could somehow be adapted to exclude orientations with induced $3-$paths.

> II. Are there any more of these other than $C_5$, apart from trivial examples on less than $4$ vertices?

Originally I thought these would constitute an infinite family of graphs, but to my surprise I have been unable to think of even one other example.  Does the condition preclude graphs above a certain order?

> III.  Can anyone help me construct an algorithm to check for graphs of this type on $6$ or more vertices?

I can use MAGMA and Mathematica for the language, or $C$ if that's what you want.  (Though that might be a bit low level for these purposes!)

Comment: Where it says "at least one orientation", I think you mean "at least one *such* orientation"?

Comment: Yes I did, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9390220N) may very well be the answer

*Chao, Chong-Yun; Chen, Zhibo*, [**On uniquely 3-colorable graphs**](https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(93)90220-N), Discrete Math. 112, No. 1-3, 21-27 (1993). [ZBL0780.05021](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0780.05021)..

Answer (score 1):

You might find an answer in Stanley, Acyclic orientations of graphs, Discrete Math 5 (1973) 171-178, available [here](https://math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/pubs/pubfiles/18.pdf). Stanley proves, among other things, that if $G$ is a graph with $p$ vertices, and $\chi(x)$ is the chromatic polynomial of $G$, then $(-1)^p\chi(-1)$ is the number of acyclic orientations of $G$.

Comment: I saw this article while researching the problem and considered including it in my post.  I am unsure how to reduce this to insist that the orientation is unique up to isomorphism.  Further I do not know how exactly to interpret the chromatic polynomial under the conditions that the graphs are triangle free.  Any advice would be appreciated; I am not a graph theorist.

Comment: Sorry, neither am I.